# Sign a message in javascript

Tags: javascript, myetherwallet

I want to sign a message with my ethereum account in a javascript application.

I do not want to work in a web-browser or with metamask.

I want to build a stand alone javascript program.

Is there a way to do that with ethereumjs-wallet for example ? I have searched for tutorials and i did not found anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sign a message using your private key to confirm your identity:

```
data = "Hello bro";
privateKey = "YOUR-PRIVATE-KEY";

const Web3 = require("web3");
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);

async function main() {
  console.log(await web3.eth.accounts.sign(data, privateKey));
}
main();
```

Output:

```
pam@g3:~/web3sign$ node main.js
{ message: 'Hello bro',
  messageHash:
   '0x24901329ae47c41fa608d792f3a292f777daeed7cf7c41743590cb00ae898efd',
  v: '0x1c',
  r:
   '0x2537f4ba476ea221ddfb091c14e763d9396a82ff482039086389d324c4099de0',
  s:
   '0x5f1c896355123c7d74c39e4ac4908bf6e4427b219e15a0b809c87b5240393f77',
  signature:
   '0x2537f4ba476ea221ddfb091c14e763d9396a82ff482039086389d324c4099de05f1c896355123c7d74c39e4ac4908bf6e4427b219e15a0b809c87b5240393f771c' }
```

Referneced from [web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-accounts.html#sign).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does web3 need to connect to an Ethereum node ? This can works offline ? And how can i check signature ?

Comment: You have to initiate the web3 instance. Let me update my answer with the code.

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me where the signature will be computed ? On a local endpoint ? Should i install something (rpc server) ? Thanks

Comment: You need an infura key to connect to. In the above code, it is mentioned as `RPC-URL`. Visit: https://infura.io/ or check this: https://link.medium.com/Sc64Avssdfb

Comment: Yes but how can i compute this signature on my local computer, without working with ethereum network ?

Comment: yes, you can compute this message without connecting to a node. Just keep the RPC-URL as blank and it will work fine. All you need is your private key to sign a message.

Check the updated code.